# Global taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want to use a taxonomy for all my custom post types.
Is this possible with the taxonomies in WordPress?

Let's say I've an owm custom post type for movies, games and music.
Now I want to add the taxomomy "genre" to all of them to build an archive page to display all custom post types for the genre.

Comment: yea, it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I've found it. I can comma seperate the post types like this:

```html
register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'post', ' page' ), $args );
```